# Getting min and max datime for each date in csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, data-science

I'm kind of new to data science and Python.

First of all, do you suggest using any other Library than pandas when dealing with huge dataset (100K+ rows)?

Second of all, let me expose to you my current problem.

I have a Dataset in which I have a Datetime column, to make it easy to understand, let's say I only have a Datetime column named `date_col`.

Here's what my `date_col` values looks like:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'dt_col': ["2019-03-13 08:12:23", "2019-03-13 07:10:18", "2019-03-13 08:12:23", "2019-03-15 10:35:53", "2019-03-20 11:12:23", "2019-03-20 08:12:23"]})

                dt_col
0  2019-03-13 08:12:23
1  2019-03-13 07:10:18
2  2019-03-13 08:12:23
3  2019-03-15 10:35:53
4  2019-03-20 11:12:23
5  2019-03-20 08:12:23
```

I want to extract foreach day the minimum and the maximum hour or `datetime`, for example for `2019-03-13`, I want to extract `2019-03-13 07:10:18` and `2019-03-13 08:12:23`.

I thought about:

1. Getting distinct dates without the time from my DataFrame
2. Foreach of these dates, getting the min and max corresponding date from my Dataframe

I'm kind of stuck at step 2 as I don't know how to really achieve this in Python, I mean I can do it the "old way" with some loops but I don't think that it will do the job with a large Dataset.

Btw, here's what I've done for step 1:

```
dates=pd.to_datetime(df.dt_col)
distinc_dates=dates.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").unique()
```

Once I got those min and max, I want to generate datetime rows between each min and max datetime, for example between `2019-03-13 07:10:18` and `2019-03-13 08:12:23`, I want to get `2019-03-13 07:10:18`, `2019-03-13 07:10:19`, `2019-03-13 07:10:20`, `2019-03-13 07:10:21`, `2019-03-13 07:10:22`,..... until `2019-03-13 08:12:23`.

I think this can be achieved using `pd.date_range`. So once I have got my min and max, I'm thinking user using `pd.date_tange` to do something like this:

```
dates=[]
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    dates.append(pd.date_range(start=row['min'], end=row['max'], freq='1S'))
print(dates)
```

But I know that iterrows is slow asf, so I'm asking you guys for the best way to achieve this when having huge dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case `dt_col` is not dtype `datetime`, you need convert it to datetime

```
df.dt_col = pd.to_datetime(df.dt_col)
```

Next, try this

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.dt_col.dt.date).dt_col.agg(['min', 'max'])

Out[555]:
                           min                 max
dt_col
2019-03-13 2019-03-13 07:10:18 2019-03-13 08:12:23
2019-03-15 2019-03-15 10:35:53 2019-03-15 10:35:53
2019-03-20 2019-03-20 08:12:23 2019-03-20 11:12:23
```

---

After having min and max. You may create range in seconds by `pd.date_range` or resampling. I think `pd.date_range` with listcomp may faster resampling in your case. Here it is

```
time_arr = [pd.date_range(df1.loc[ix,'min'], df1.loc[ix,'max'], freq='S') 
                       for ix in df1.index]
```

Or

```
time_arr = [pd.date_range(x[0], x[1], freq='S') for x in df1.values]

Out[640]:
[DatetimeIndex(['2019-03-13 07:10:18', '2019-03-13 07:10:19',
                '2019-03-13 07:10:20', '2019-03-13 07:10:21',
                '2019-03-13 07:10:22', '2019-03-13 07:10:23',
                '2019-03-13 07:10:24', '2019-03-13 07:10:25',
                '2019-03-13 07:10:26', '2019-03-13 07:10:27',
                ...
                '2019-03-13 08:12:14', '2019-03-13 08:12:15',
                '2019-03-13 08:12:16', '2019-03-13 08:12:17',
                '2019-03-13 08:12:18', '2019-03-13 08:12:19',
                '2019-03-13 08:12:20', '2019-03-13 08:12:21',
                '2019-03-13 08:12:22', '2019-03-13 08:12:23'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=3726, freq='S'),
 DatetimeIndex(['2019-03-15 10:35:53'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='S'),
 DatetimeIndex(['2019-03-20 08:12:23', '2019-03-20 08:12:24',
                '2019-03-20 08:12:25', '2019-03-20 08:12:26',
                '2019-03-20 08:12:27', '2019-03-20 08:12:28',
                '2019-03-20 08:12:29', '2019-03-20 08:12:30',
                '2019-03-20 08:12:31', '2019-03-20 08:12:32',
                ...
                '2019-03-20 11:12:14', '2019-03-20 11:12:15',
                '2019-03-20 11:12:16', '2019-03-20 11:12:17',
                '2019-03-20 11:12:18', '2019-03-20 11:12:19',
                '2019-03-20 11:12:20', '2019-03-20 11:12:21',
                '2019-03-20 11:12:22', '2019-03-20 11:12:23'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=10801, freq='S')]
```

---

**Note**: if you dataset is too big and you create range by seconds, you may run out of memory and crash.

Comment: Is there a shortcut to use the min and max with a pd.date_range to generate a datetime foreach second between them ? or i'll have to it with a loop?

Comment: @lefragan: could you edit the question to add more detail and example on what you mean?

Comment: Yeah sure, sorry, i should've done this in the first place. Its done now

Comment: @Arès: You may use list comprehension. It is faster than loop of iterrows. Check my edited.